# Most of the D-pad buttons do not respond when we are in a WebView in Android TV

Tags: flutter-inappwebview

I´m using flutter_inappwebview 6.0.0-beta.22.

```
This is my flutter doctor output:

    [√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.7, on Microsoft Windows [Versi¢n 10.0.19045.2846], locale es-ES)
    [√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
    [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
    [√] Chrome - develop for the web
    [√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.4.4)   
    [√] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
    [√] VS Code (version 1.77.3)
    [√] Connected device (4 available)
    [√] HTTP Host Availability
```

Here you can download the sample code that reproduces the issue https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DQzb3TVtOlL76HeVF-3-KRj7syzsQsvo/view?usp=sharing

First of all, I want to mention that I am very new to Flutter and this may be a simple problem. I apologize if I am wasting your time.

```
The attached application, a very simple version to describe the problem, consists of two screens:
    - The first screen simply contains two buttons. Each button calls a WebView.
    - The second screen is the WebView itself, which simply opens a YouTube video.
    - On an Android mobile device, it works perfectly: in the WebView, the user can manipulate the video, press play, stop, and everything else that YouTube allows 
    - However, on an Android TV, using the D-pad, the only button that works is the back button, none of the other buttons work.
    - For the main page, which does not have a WebView, it was enough to use Shortcuts with LogicalKeySet to manage the D-pad buttons, but the same approach does not work on the page with the WebView.
```

I have tried different approaches to solve the problem but none of them have worked.
Does anyone know what I should do to make all the D-pad buttons work correctly in the WebView?
Thank you very much